# How to fix Plesk Onyx not showing PostgreSQL DB size

Tags: postgresql, plesk, postgresql-10, plesk-onyx

Fresh install of ‪Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS‬ running Plesk Onyx Version 17.8.11 Update #60 with just minor tweak so far; used the built in support and installed a PostgreSQL DB Server plus initial database that I then moved to another partition (changed the default so to speak)..

As part of moving the one database that existed I did a :

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /home/plesk

nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
```

Changed the default location to reflect my partion for it

data_directory = '/home/plesk/postgresql/10/main'

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

This initial change resulted in the DB in Plesk just showing a loading wheel for # of tables and size.

I have tried to fix it by editing my /etc/psa/psa.conf and changing PGSQL_DATA_D to reflect the database move.

```
PGSQL_DATA_D /home/plesk/postgresql/10/main
```

The two last PGSQL related entries in that file remains:

```
PGSQL_CONF_D /etc/postgresql/10/main
PGSQL_BIN_D /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin
```

The fix I tried did change something; instead of showing a loading cog the Plesk UI now shows > Tables: null and Size: 0 B? So not a fix but at least it seems more correct than before... but I have no clue how to proceed to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I maybe forgot to do a > service sw-cp-server restart > after making the changes or something else fixed this in the meantime as it is now showing # of tables and size. Case Closed.